# Why is Setting a SQL Server Bit to "false" in a stored procedure definition valid?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Bits are often used in SQL Server to represent true and false however you cannot literally assign true and false to them it must be 1 or 0.

I recently stumbled across the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
@parameter bit = false
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

Why is it valid? Especially when setting a bit to false in the body of the stored procedure is not.

If you query the parameter with a select it is indeed set to 0 which represents false.

Comment: What happens when you execute it?

Comment: It executes fine. If you select the parameter it is indeed set to false.

Comment: SQL 2008 R2 edited main question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SQL Server has in built functionality to convert string values `'true'` to `1` and `'false'` to `0`:

Run this code and see:

```
DECLARE @someval BIT = 'true'

SELECT @someval

SET @someval = 'false'

SELECT @someval
```

**Reference:**

### [bit (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177603.aspx)

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

As @hvd states in comments, the reason the declaration works without quotes in your sample is based on quotes being optional in parameter assignments of a stored procedure declaration.

**Reference:**

### [Parameter Assignment to unquoted string](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/278399/parameter-assignment-to-unquoted-string)

> In a stored procedure definition, a parameter can be assigned a default string value that is an 'unquoted' string.
>
> ...this is very widely used legacy behavior that needs to be maintained for compatibility reasons. The same behavior can be seen when passing parameters in an exec statement.

Comment: This is a possibly good partial answer. It doesn't explain how an *unquoted* `false` works for the OP, though.

Comment: And the reason for that is that in a few rare contexts, one being default values for stored procedure parameters, quoting is optional. [Parameter Assignment to unquoted string](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/278399/parameter-assignment-to-unquoted-string)

Comment: MS' response to that connect item for the "Parameter Assignment to unquoted string" is hilarious. We would but ...legacy. 
I saw this usage in some dev code today and was blowing my mind why it wasn't having an error. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign false to bit variable in any place than procedure parameters declaration - in that area SQL knows you mean the same as 0, but not in procedure actual text. Only in parameters.